# Windows 10 blurry appilication icon in the taskbar

Tags: windows-10

I have created an .ico for my application in WPF, I included the following resolutions in it: 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48 and 256x256.

The icon of the application is displayed correctly in every place except for the taskbar...
trying to find whats going on I created a test .ico that includes all resolutions from 16x16 to 32x32, It turns out that for the taskbar, windows 10 do not use the 24x24 as it fits... but they resize the 32x32...
is there any workaround for this issue? probably there is... or how other programs have crispy icons in the taskbar...

I also found this thread from 2015 which also addresses the same issue:

[Taskbar scales down icons, using larger sizes and making them blurry](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/taskbar-scales-down-icons-using-larger-sizes-and/67e43f31-764f-42f2-88fd-fbe125879e12)

seems like nothing changed since then

Thanks in advance